# How to find source of system running slow clock?

Tags: linux, performance, time, gentoo

I've a problem on one of my Gentoo server. After some time, the clock starts running very very slow. It takes about **one minute for one second to go**. The major problem is that not only the clock is impacted but the system is running slow as well. If I run `top`, it takes more than 10 seconds to open. A `sleep 1` takes about a minute.

There is no load on the system, almost nothing is running. I'm running the kernel 4.0.5. The hardware clock is running fine.

What could be the source of such problem ?

Here is the clocksource information:

```
# cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource
refined-jiffies jiffies tsc
# cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
refined-jiffies
```

Comment: Check the current clock source. (This may be failing hardware).

Comment: Reboot into `knoppix` to compare.  If `knoppix` runs without a clock problem, then there's a problem with your kernel or a hardware problem.  If `knoppix` has the same clock issue, then it's a hardware issue.

Comment: @KonradGajewski I added information about the clocksource. It is using refined-jiffies. Could that be an issue since I'm running a system with "dynticks idle" ?

Comment: Try using jiffies and tsc and see what happens.

Comment: Did you compile your own kernel (I am not really good with Gentoo).

Comment: Take a look at the known issues with dynticks_idle, you could try changing the interrupt handling strategy to rule that out: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/NO_HZ.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the clocksource to tsc fixed the problem.